# Javascript Average of Array of Objects property

Tags: javascript

Im stuck on how I would go about writing this calculation out. Basically. I have an array of objects and I need to know the average level achieved (incentive_level). I believe in this case it is 0

```
[
  {incentive_level: 0, users: 183},
  {incentive_level: 1, users: 72},
  {incentive_level: 2, users: 57},
  {incentive_level: 3, users: 9}
]
```

Comment: How would you perform this calculation by hand?  Given that, what have you tried in code?

Comment: @Sean That's asking how to do averages grouped by a property. There's no grouping in this question.

Comment: Why do you think the answer is 0? The average of `0, 1, 2, 3` is `6 / 4 == 1.5`

Comment: @Barmar if you skip the first step of filtering the property, that linked question's answer is exactly what is needed

Comment: I suspect that in this case he also needs to multiply by the number of users that achieved each level. But it's not clear.

Comment: Sorry the avg level achieved im told in this case is 1. I can not avg by 0, 1, 2, 3 is 6 / 4 == 1.5. It is based on the user count as well. thats why I am stuck on how to do the calculation. And yes im female thank you @Sean :)

Comment: So it is weighted average then?

Comment: Can you update your question to include greater details and your desired result?

Comment: Would it be: (sum of (incentive_level * users)) / (sum of users) ?  Because that's not 0 either.  Are you sure you're looking for the *average* (mean) and not the *mode*?

Comment: @David yes I think that is right I would have to calculate it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the records, keeping track of total # of users and cumulative score, then do the division at the end. Something like:

```js
var list = [
  {incentive_level: 0, users: 183},
  {incentive_level: 1, users: 72},
  {incentive_level: 2, users: 57},
  {incentive_level: 3, users: 9}
]

var totalUsers = 0
var totalScore = 0

for(var i=0; i< list.length;i++){
  totalUsers += list[i].users
  totalScore += (list[i].users * list[i].incentive_level)
}

console.log("Total Users: " + totalUsers)
console.log("Total Score: " + totalScore)

var average = totalScore/totalUsers

console.log(average)
```